# Find maximum span of two digits together in R Programming

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<- data.frame(a = 0,b=0,c=1,d=1,e=0,f=1,g=1,h=1)
```

`print(df)` would give this result

```
 a b c d e f g h

 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

Now, I need to find out the span of 1s together , which is maximum. In the above scenario, we have 1s together twice (column C and column D) before zero comes in the next column and thrice next (column f,g,h). I want result to be something like this, as 3 is max of 2 and 3.

```
 a b c d e f g h ***Max_Span***

 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ***3***
```

Is there a easy way to do it rather than jump each byte at once and check its value with previous one? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the function `rle`.

Here an example to see what it does (counts the number of sequences):

```
vect <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
rle(vect)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 1 2 3 1
  values : num [1:4] 1 0 1 0
```

Edit:

if you want only a particular values just use `which`:

```
rle_vect <- rle(vect) #first we assign the output from rle
rle_vect$lengths[which(rle_vect$values==1)] # then we can access where values==1
#[1] 1 3
```

In your case you want the max number of `lengths` for only `1`s:

```
rle_1 <- rle(df[1,])
max(rle_1$lengths[which(rle_1$values==1)])
#[1] 3
```

Data:

```
df[1, ]
#  a b c d e f g h
#1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Hi, see my update, you just need to save the `rle` then use `which` to extract only for the `1` from `values`.

Comment: Thanks... I just converted the result of rle to a data frame and then exxtracted. However, your solution is simple. Thanks much :)

Comment: Btw, I have another question, perhaps this must be a new one instead of comments. Anyways I ll go ahead:  Suppose I wish to pick the position of the first '1' which would become part of the maximum span of 1s, can I do it from rle only? Say in above example, 1 in the 4th byte is the 1st of 1s in max span. I want another column that has info on starting point of 1s which has max span, in this case its 4. Please advice

Comment: I'm sorry I cant' seem to understand. Probably you'll be better off asking a new question, just make a reproducible example and the expected output :)